# Variable type of "mon" in PHP getdate() is INT but echoes as STRING

Tags: php, getdate

I'm a beginner re-learning to code and building a simple "dashboard" in PHP. I constructed a database with information about my friends, including their date of birth and I want my dashboard to tell me, if any of my friends has birthday that given day.

So far I've managed to extract today's date and display it (I apologize for the switch, it was the only thing I was able to come up with):

```
//Date
$today = getdate();

foreach ($today as $key => $value) {
  switch ($key) {
    case "mday":
      $day = $value;
      echo "Today is " . $value;
      break;
    case "month":
      echo " " . $value;
      echo "<br />";
    case "mon":
      $mon = $value;
      break;
  }
}

echo $mon;
echo $day;
```

BUT as in my db the date_of_birth format reads as string (e.g. 1987-02-14) in need a numeric value for month. It should be "mon", as both in the documentation and when I var_dump $today "mon" is supposed to be numeric value/int. But no. When echoed it echoes "February".

Why? Why is that? What am I missing? I will be grateful for any advice.

Comment: You don't break in `month`, so it continues on to `mon`

Comment: For the love of all that's holy. I've looked at it 100 times!!!
Thank you SO much.